# Redux getting cannot read property map of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to fetch some data through redux, and trying to render it in Fedp.js component. But I'm getting an error in mapping. can you please tell me where I'm going wrong in the whole boilerplate?

productActions.js

```
export function fetchProducts() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch({
      type: 'FETCH_PRODUCTS_REQUEST'
    });
    return fetch('/products')
      .then(response => response.json().then(body => ({ response, body })))
      .then(({ response, body }) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          dispatch({
            type: 'FETCH_PRODUCTS_FAILURE',
            error: body.error
          });
        } else {
          dispatch({
            type: 'FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS',
            products: body.products
          });
        }
      });
    }
 }
```

productReducer.js

```
const initialState = {
  products: []
};


export  function productsReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_PRODUCTS_REQUEST':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: true
      });
    case 'FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: false,
        products: action.products
      });
    case 'FETCH_PRODUCTS_FAILURE':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: false,
        error: action.error
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

indexreducer.js:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { productsReducer } from './productReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  products: productsReducer
});
```

configureStore.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/indexReducer';

function configureStore(initialState) {
  return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  );
}

export default configureStore
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from './App.js'
import configureStore from './Redux/store/configureStore';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';



const store = configureStore();


ReactDOM.render( <Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Fedp.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchProducts } from '../Redux/actions/productAction';




class Fedp extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchProducts();
  }


  render() { 
    return (
            <ul>
            {this.props.products.map((details, index)=>{
              <li key={item.id}> {details.name} + {details.price} </li>
        })}
          </ul>
    );
  }
}




function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    products: state.products
  };
}


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    fetchProducts: function() {
      dispatch(fetchProducts());
    }
  };
}




export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Fedp);
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that **body** has a property called **products**? If body is already the array of product objects, you are dispatching a payload of undefined to the reducer. If you console.log() body.products in the else statement does it actually print an array?

Comment: You were right. I changed the body to :dispatch({
        type: 'FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS',
        products: data
      });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `mapStateToProps` method, you are returning the value of  `state.products` as `products`.  But `state.products` is the reducer itself and not the array of results you are fetching from the API Call.

This block below creates a redux `state` object with all the keys mentioned in the parameters of `combineReducers`.

```
export default combineReducers({
    products: productsReducer
});
```

So `state.products` is nothing but your `productsReducer` as shown above. Now the values that you fetched from the API call are stored in the `products` key inside the `productsReducer`. Hence, the correct way to access these values would be `state.products.products`.

Modify your `mapStateToProps` to the below block, and it shall work.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        products: state.products.products
    };
}
```

Comment: This is what i'm trying to figure out for a while: `products: state.products.products`. I have to map over the product list this way: `this.props.products.products.map`. most common pattern of returning is ` products: state.products`. Where is it all going wrong?

Comment: @Deke Nothing is “wrong” with that. It’s not pretty, but it’s not wrong. If you look at examples of Redux, just give the actual array of product objects within the “products” store key a name such as “items” or “elements” or similar. I personally wouldn’t overthink it.